# not able to bind a DropDownList in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to `MVC`. I'm trying to bind a dropdownlist but facing an issue.

Following code of DataLayer:

```
public List<DataLayer.Customer> GetCustomers()
      {
          return obj.Customers.ToList();

      }
```

Controller Code:

```
 [Authorize]
         public ActionResult CreateOrder()
         {
             ViewBag.Message = "Crearte Order";
             ViewBag.Customers = manageOrder.GetCustomers();
             return View();
         }
```

View Code:

```
@Html.DropDownList("SelectedMovieType", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>) ViewBag.Customers)
```

Getting following error when it try to bind the `DropDownList`

**enable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[DataLayer.Customer]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem]'.**

Let me know that how i can get ride of this issue.

Comment: I'd recommend browsing around a bit more since there are a lot of posts about this.

Comment: What goes your's if you have answer for my problem. thanks for comment.

Comment: The error tells you exactly what the problem is.  When the compiler says it can't cast it from one type to another, it means that your source type is NOT castable to that... because it's something else totally different that isn't compatible.  You need to create a data item that is compatible (such as creating a new collection of SelectListItem).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ViewBag.Customers` should be of type `List<SelectListItem>`.

Controller Code:

```
ViewBag.Customers = manageOrder.GetCustomers().Select(c => new SelectListItem { Text = c.TextProperty, Value = c.ValueProperty }).ToList();
```

View Code:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Customers")
```